# eBiking and swimming in Austrian lakes

Tags: bicycles, austria, mountains, swimming, lakes

I am looking to spend this year's summer holidays in Austria. Last year I was in Seefeld in Tirol and I really enjoyed renting ebikes and just exploring around and also swimming in lakes around the area. Could you suggest me similar place but in a different part of Austria? Preferrably with not too tough trails and lakes with warm water. I will be travelling with car, so transport is not a problem.